# How to enable XMPPFramework to print raw XML on console

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I was wondering how I can enable XMPPFramework (https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) to print raw XML on the console e.g; like this one.

```
SEND: <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='dev.doctome.org'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from the following thread.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xmppframework/6cpoAHKBpNg

Basically you have to add logger with `XMPP_LOG_FLAG_SEND_RECV` flag.

```
[DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance] withLogLevel:XMPP_LOG_FLAG_SEND_RECV];
```